# Surround specific webform elements with a div

Tags: webforms

As the title describes, I am to style a webform and for that i need to surround specific fields in divs in order to give them their CSS properties and I have no idea how I should go about doing that. Also I'd like to do the same to the Submit button.

I've caught the form with `hook_form_alter` but no idea what to do after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a div?

Just use a field set and hide label and turn off the collapsible feature.

If anything this is more semantic than using a div in splitting up fields in a form. Visually will look excately the same and you can also use CSS class generated from the field set name in your styling.

Comment: yeap ended up using that after all. First time I am asked to create a form and was unfamilliar with the Fieldset component. Thanks anyway and here's a green check for you!

Comment: do you care to share how you added the 'fields' to a fieldset? can you do this with something like `$form['field_name'] = array('#fieldset' => 'fieldsetname');` ?

Comment: You can do this via the UI. To do it programatically you would have to follow the FAPI instructions.